# Missing main.exe when installing llama2 model

Tags: python, c++, git, llama, llama-cpp-python

I am trying to install a language model called llama2 from [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama).

Followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@karankakwani/build-and-run-llama2-llm-locally-a3b393c1570e) with some necessary adjustments (see reproducability below), but in step 7 it wants to use a Main.exe which is not there. I looked in several Llama2 repos but no one provides a Main.exe.

How do I find the Main.exe that is missing here to run the llama2 model?

**Reproducability**
I have done the following:

- in Git Bash: `git clone https://github.com/sychhq/llama-cpp-setup.git && cd llama-cpp-setup && chmod +x setup.sh && ./setup.sh`
- It struggles with SSL licences so I add `git config --global http.sslbackend schannel` and rerun line above. It now works and asks for settings. I use default for both questions so press enter twice.
- It takes 6 mins to download en ends up in C:/Users/…/llama-cpp-setup
- I now clone the llama repo by `git clone https://github.com/facebookresearch/llama.git`
- I now install wget and put it in `C:/Windows/System32`
- Then I run `/bin/bash ./download.sh` where I put the URL that I requested from https://ai.meta.com/resources/models-and-libraries/llama-downloads/
- I updated to Python 11 and run `python -m venv llama2` from `cd llama.cpp`
- Then to activate the model (source) `llama2\Scripts\activate` and `python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt`
- Then `python3 convert.py --outfile models/7B/ggml-model-f16.bin --outtype f16 ../../llama-cpp-setup/llama/llama-2-7b --vocab-dir ../../llama-cpp-setup//llama/llama  (let op de paths!)`
- `quantize  ./models/7B/ggml-model-f16.bin ./models/7B/ggml-model-q4_0.bin q4_0` comprimises the model. This happens from a quantize.exe program that is visible in the File Explorer.
- Finally I run `./main -m ./models/7B/ggml-model-q4_0.bin -n 1024 --repeat_penalty 1.0 --color -i -r "User:" -f ./prompts/chat-with-bob.txt` but it cannot find a main.exe . Which is obviously true, because there is no Main.exe in the directory (I checked in the Explorer).